# How can i remove an whole XML Block just by knowing an element inside it

Tags: c#, xml, linq

everyone i have a question on how to delete an block of elements from my xml file while knowing only the text value of one item inside it. There are hundreds of the the same blocks where the only difference is the ID values and the text that i know to delete the block.

```
public static void deleteBlock() {
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\VisualStudioProjects\bausteine\modul.xml");
        foreach (XElement xEle in xelement.Descendants("SW.Blocks.CompileUnit"))
        {
            var complete = xEle;
            foreach(var item in xEle.Descendants("Text"))
            {
                if (item.Value=="The only thing i know to delete the Block")       
                {
                    complete.Remove();
                    break; // The Answer
                }

            }
           xelement.Save(@"C:\Program Files(x86)\Tools\VisualStudioProjects\Baustein_1.xml");
        }
```

I though i could look first for the element with the name SW.Blocks.CompileUnit then look inside it for the Text value and if it matches mine then it should delete the block and it should go through all blocks. It finds the block i want but deletes everything else and saves the block that i want to be deleted. Then it gives me Null Exception.

```
<SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="85" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
    <AttributeList> 
     <ObjectList>
      <MultilingualText ID="86" CompositionName="Comment">
        <ObjectList>
          <MultilingualTextItem ID="87" CompositionName="Items">
            <AttributeList>
              <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
              <Text />
            </AttributeList>
          </MultilingualTextItem>
        </ObjectList>
      </MultilingualText>
      <MultilingualText ID="88" CompositionName="Title">
        <ObjectList>
          <MultilingualTextItem ID="89" CompositionName="Items">
            <AttributeList>
              <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
              <Text>The Only thing i know to delete the Block</Text>
            </AttributeList>
          </MultilingualTextItem>
        </ObjectList>
      </MultilingualText>
    </ObjectList>
  </SW.Blocks.CompileUnit>
```

That is one of the blocks of the xml data. That is also the one that my codes leaves while deleting everything else. I hope i explained it a little better now. I dont know why its deleting everything else except the block and why is it giving me a null exception. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're saving `complete` rather than `xelement`, so of course it appears to be removing everything other than the block.

Comment: I am wondering if this could be done faster and easier with XSLT ...

Comment: The problem i have right know is that when i find the block with the right text and remove it i get for the next loop and 'System.NullReferenceException' and it stops so i cant save anymore.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah i've forgot to put the line in where i put the save under the code. Thanks still :D

Comment: "The problem i have right know is that when i find the block with the right text and remove it i get for the next loop and 'System.NullReferenceException' and it stops so i cant save anymore. " That information should be in the question then, along with what you've done to investigate why you are seeing that exception, and the complete stack trace. I'd suggest that you can *stop* looping when you've called `complete.Remove` though. If you provide a [mcve], I'd be happy to test a simple fix...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Man. An break was all i need for it to work. I would upload my code but the problem is it has over 15000 lines and it was hard just to upload this 100 because the formating. It would be nice if i could upload my code files so other could also work it in the future if they need to. Thanks again for every answer. :D

Comment: The problem is deleting items from a list.  When you delete item 3 from a list all the items higher than 3 get moved down one item number which then leads to your exception. The solution is to start at end of list and move toward the beginning :  var item in xEle.Descendants("Text"); for(int i = item.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--){ item[i].Remove();}

Comment: @jdweng Smart solution. Thanks. Would never think about that. Gonna implement it. ;)

Comment: "I would upload my code but the problem is it has over 15000 lines" - no-one ever suggested uploading everything. That's why I specifically said a *minimal* reproducible example. I'm sure you don't need 15,000 lines of code to reproduce it.

Comment: @jdweng: There's a simpler approach in this case: `if (xEle.Descendants("Text").Any(x => x.Value == "The only thing i know to delete the Block") { xEle.Remove(); }` There's no need to have an inner foreach loop at all. (The outer loop may want changing as well, although the simplest option here is usually just to call `ToList()` to materialize the results once and not invalidate the results when deleting the item.)

Comment: @JonSkeet : That solution will work with Xml Linq but will not work with other type of lists.  I was just explaining the same programming issue that of answered thousands of times.  Also the Any solution uses more memory than my solution.

Comment: @jdweng: I was addressing the question being asked, which *is* LINQ to XML. And no, I don't believe that `Any` will use more memory in this particular case, given that your solution requires a list. (The code you've written would actually compile given that `item` would be an `XElement`, which doesn't have an indexer or a `Count()` method.) Using `Any` to determine whether a specific element needs to be removed or not expresses the intention clearly *and* would be more efficient I believe.

Comment: @jdweng: As it happens, using the `Remove` extension method makes this even clearer. If you believe your solution will be clearer and/or more efficient than that, I'd suggest you add an answer with code that will actually compile and work.

Comment: @JonSkeet : same question appears again : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220449/removing-an-element-in-string-list-in-c-gives-errorargumentoutofrangeexceptio?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng: Except that's *not* the same question, is it? That's a question about removing an item from a list. This is a question about removing an element from an XML document. Again, if you think your approach is better for *this* question, do feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I'd suggest using the [`Remove` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.extensions.remove?view=net-6.0), after determining which elements need removing. Here's a complete program to demonstrate this - it just needs a suitable `input.xml` file.

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var element = XElement.Load("input.xml");
element
    .Descendants("SW.Blocks.CompileUnit")
    .Where(x => x.Descendants("Text")
                 .Any(x => x.Value == "The only thing i know to delete the Block"))
    .Remove();
element.Save("result.xml");
```

That's not only efficient, but it's more self-descriptive than the manual code going through descendants one at a time.