# Removing an element in string list in c#, gives error(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)

Tags: c#, list, loops, unity-game-engine, filter

I'm trying to filter my string list by getting input, but get this error:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

```
private List<string> title = new List<string>();
private int cellNumber { get; set; }
private int counter = 0;

inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { Search(cellNumber-counter); });
```

```
public void Search(int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        if (!title[i].ToLower().Contains(inputField.text.ToLower()) && inputField.text != "")
        {
            title.RemoveAt(i);
            counter++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First, is your title list greater then size when you call search? , second is your cellNumber greater than counter otherwise your search will get a negative input parameter.

Comment: @Rajas Initially the cellNumber is 3 and also title size is 3.

Comment: When removing item 3 from a list all items greater than 3 drop down one count.  So when removing from list you have start from end and move towards beginning : for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: Or more simply, use `List<T>.RemoveAll` with a predicate, assuming it's meant to find all matches. It's not clear what `size` is expected to do here. (I'd suggest only calling it at all if `inputField.Text` is non-empty though, and use a case-insensitive string comparison instead of lower-casing everything.)

Comment: Or you can keep going forwards, but remember to decrement both your counter (`i`) and your endpoint (`size`). That's generally more fiddly than going backwards, but you don't *have* to start at the end.

Comment: Thanks @all for helping me to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have hits your list size decreases for each removed item.

So even assuming you are passing in the correct `size` of the list, the iterator variable `i` at some point at the end runs longer than the **new smaller size** of your list after removing items => ArgumentOutOfRangeException!

---

What you could do is keep updating the size and skip `i++` whenever you remove an item like e.g.

```
public void Search()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputField.text))
    {
        return;
    }

    var size = title.Count;
    var i = 0;

    while(i < size)
    {
        if (!title[i].ToLower().Contains(inputField.text.ToLower()))
        {
            title.RemoveAt(i);
            size--;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that there is a simple method that already covers this without further effort: [`List<t>.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall)

```
public void Search()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputField.text))
    {
        return;
    }

    // remove all matches
    title.RemoveAll(t => !t.ToLower().Contains(inputField.text.ToLower()));
}
```

---

Though you might be even more interested in using [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) in order to return a new collection with the hits without modifying the original one

```
using System.Linq;

...

public string[] Search()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputField.text))
    {
        return new string[0];
    }

    // remove all matches
    return title.Where(t => t.ToLower().Contains(inputField.text.ToLower())).ToArray();
}
```